# analyticity of an integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, uniform-convergence

Studying $$f(z)=\int_0^1 g(z,x)\ dx $$

where  $g(z,x)$ is analytic in the open unit disk $D$ for all $x\in [0,1]$ and

continuous for $|z| <1$ and $0\leq x \leq1$.Now,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}  [1/n \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} g(z,k/n)]=\int_0^1 g(z,x)\ dx$$ by continuity.

Is the above convergence uniform in  $D$?

$D$:=open unit disk

Comment: It won't in general be uniform, but it will be locally uniform, which is sufficient. The usual way to deduce the analyticity of such integrals is Morera's theorem.

Comment: since it is uniform convergence on an "open" set , I don't know how to deal..

Comment: @Daniel Fischer  locally uniform is easy but this should be true in  all of D..At least the paper I am studying asserts that..

Comment: What "should be true in all of $D$"? In general, the convergence $R_n(z) \to f(z)$, where $R_n$ is the Riemann sum, is not uniform on $D$. If that is asserted, then there must be stronger assumptions - e.g. that $g$ is continuous on $\overline{D}\times [0,1]$ - or the assertion is false. For practically everything one does, the _locally uniform_ convergence in $D$, which we have, is good enough.

Comment: ok I see ...ty.